# Can't get past login screen

Tags: control-panel, login

I have an EE site on 2.5.2 that just reloads the login screen whenever I click login. This is happening for all users and user groups, and in multiple browsers.

EngineHosting suggested I edit the config file to add:

$config[‘admin_session_type’] = “c”;

This did not solve, unfortunately. Any thoughts?

Many thanks.

Comment: Eric, this question has been asked a ton on EESE. Have you tried some of the suggested fixes from other posts?  http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/search?q=login

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the following and change the cookie prefix:

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
$config['cookie_path'] = "";
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['admin_session_type'] = "s";
$config['user_session_type'] = "c";
$config['require_ip_for_login'] = "n";
$config['require_ip_for_posting'] = "n"; 
$config['secure_forms'] = "n";
```